# Theming for ionic 2 application

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, coding-style, themes

I have created application in ionic 2 and is completed, now I want to create another app with same codebase but with different theme colour/images.

I want to know the way by which I can conditionally define the color and style variable in theme/variable.scss src/app.scss.

I hope my question make sense and is clear to all. Please suggest the best way/practice to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can define color variables in your `.scss` files. I would not say it is good practise to keep the old overhead and put it into the new app.

Your `theme/variables.scss` could look like this:

```
$colors: (
    primary:    #488aff,
    secondary:  #32db64,
    danger:     #f53d3d,
    light:      #f4f4f4,
    dark:       #222
);
```

And on your other pages you can use these colors like this:

```
color($colors, primary);
```

So it is super easy to change the colors, because the color code (`#488aff`) is only defined at one place and the definitions in your pages are just referring to it.

**Note**: If you want to use dynamic theming, for example by time (light at day and dark at night), you can look at this repository: https://github.com/yannbf/ionic3-components/tree/master/src/pages/theming